# Extended Select Dijit doesn't work in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, dojo

Why does this work in IE10 and Firefox but **not** in IE7/8?

Dojo version 1.8, using auto-require, extending a Select with a new missing message...

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/form/Select",
], function (declare, Select) {
    return declare("mydijit.form.Select", [Select], {
        missingMessage: "Please answer this.",
        postMixInProperties: function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this._missingMsg = this.missingMessage;
        }

    });
});
```

Fails in dojo.js

```
def (line 1801) => defineModule (line 1546) =>

getModule = function(mid, referenceModule, immediate){
....
    match = mid.match(/^(.+?)\!(.*)$/); (line 1013)
```

For some reason mid is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - if you look closely at the module list it contains a comma at the end of the list, which Internet Explorer 7 interprets as meaning an undefined field follows. Later versions of IE take it in their stride.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/form/Select"
], function (declare, Select) {
    return declare("mydijit.form.Select", [Select], {
        missingMessage: "Please answer this.",
        postMixInProperties: function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this._missingMsg = this.missingMessage;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for returning and posting the solution yourself: this really helped me out!

Comment: No problem - I always try and update on what answer I've found. Personally I would have thought this is the sort of thing that should have been trapped and logged to the console....